# Apple pages quits unexpectedly when opening a specific file

Tags: mac, crash, pages

when I try to open a report that I was working on on apple pages, it didn't wanna open, and it quits immediately.
this is the error:

```
Process:               Pages [1249]
Path:                  /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/MacOS/Pages
Identifier:            com.apple.iWork.Pages
Version:               11.1 (7031.0.102)
Build Info:            Pages-7031000102000000~2 (1A104)
App Item ID:           409201541
App External ID:       842170573
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Pages [1249]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2021-06-14 19:16:44.689 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 11.0.1 (20B50)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        AB560D41-C75F-CB60-2576-E1B8A3A91708


Time Awake Since Boot: 2500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        7  Dispatch queue: TSAFontResourceRequest.Network

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1249]

.
.
.
(I couldn't copy the whole code cause it's so big)
.
.
.

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.0G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.0G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=593.8M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=593.8M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               256K        2 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                  816K        6 
CoreAnimation                       60K       11 
CoreGraphics                         4K        1 
CoreUI image data                  424K        8 
Foundation                          40K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           189.5M       92 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        8 
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
SQLite page cache                   64K        1 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       20 
Stack                             17.6M       20 
VM_ALLOCATE                       1260K       38 
__CTF                               759        1 
__DATA                            37.4M      583 
__DATA_CONST                      37.4M      397 
__DATA_DIRTY                      2184K      257 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       496.9M       34 
__OBJC_RO                         61.0M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2468K        2 
__TEXT                           554.3M      576 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
mapped file                      562.5M       58 
shared memory                       44K        5 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              2.3G     2128 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.0G     2128 

Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM 424.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Graphics: kHW_IntelHDGraphics6000Item, Intel HD Graphics 6000, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445384533303445452D45474345000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445384533303445452D45474345000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1669)
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.1f5, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi 2, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2
```

Comment: Can you open it in a text editor?

Comment: First suggestion would be to get macOS up to date. 11.0.1 was still very buggy.